# Save new entity in changeRequestInterceptor method

Tags: breeze

Im just thinkin to save some audit details of all changes on entities to database.so im have come up with that "changeRequestInterceptor" which looks like where i can implement my audit logic in.

Well,the question is simply is it possible to add this newly created entity to request payload ?

```
 var adapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('dataService');
        adapter.changeRequestInterceptor = function (saveContext, saveBundle) {
            this.getRequest = function (request, entity, index) {
                var em = saveContext.entityManager;                    

                var en = em.createEntity('DbLog',
                {
                    userId: //userId
                    logDate: new Date(),
                    log: //some log text
                });

                //How to add "en" entity to requet payload.

                return request;
            };
            this.done = function (requests) {
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm firmly with Jay in favor of creating audit records on the server, not the client. The client could care less and shouldn't bear the burden of creating the extra material nor have to burn bandwidth for that kind of stuff. It's really not a client concern.

There is a save interceptor in the Breeze-oriented server components. There is NO save interceptor in the Breeze client save pipeline.

We have such a thing in our DevForce product. After careful thought we did not bring it over to Breeze and we're confident that we were wise to leave it out. Interceptors add complexity and obscurity. Some times they are necessary (as with our server-side interceptors) but we don't think they are helpful or necessary for a client-side save operation ... for reasons I'm about to explain.

Breeze never calls `EntityManager.saveChanges` on its own. *You* do that. Which means *you* are in perfect position to decide what happens before Breeze does its thing. That includes creating supplementary entity changes just before save if that's what you need.

In our samples, we encapsulate the `EntityManager` in some kind of a service component (e.g., a "DataContext" or a "DataService"). Application layers (e.g., viewmodels) can't talk to an `EntityManager` directly; they have to go through the `DataContext` to perform persistence operation.

Your `DataContext` API should expose a "save" method (or methods) that wraps the `EntityManager.saveChanges` call with the appropriate business logic.

Follow this pattern and you'll find ample opportunities to implement pre- and post-save behaviors.

> Of course Breeze does offer save interception at lower levels of the stack. The `DataServiceAdapter`, for example, handles the details of translating between Breeze entity representation and whatever your particular backend service requires in the way of HTTP setup and JSON objects. You want these details abstracted for you when writing your `DataContext`.
>
> You might need some interception way down here ... and you'll find the requisite hooks. But now we're talking about what you can do below the Breeze entity abstraction. This feels like the wrong place to be adding/modifying/deleting entities even if it is technically possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to perform the Add on the server instead of the client.

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveWithFoo(JObject saveBundle) {
  ContextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = AddNewFoo;
  return ContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}


private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> AddNewFoo(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) 
   var foo = new Foo();
   // update the entity with any custom data. For example:
   foo.OrderDate = DateTime.Today;

   var ei = ContextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(foo);
   List<EntityInfo> fooInfos;
   if (!saveMap.TryGetValue(typeof(Foo), out fooInfos)) {
     fooInfos = new List<EntityInfo>();
     saveMap.Add(typeof(Foo), fooInfos);
   }
   fooInfos.Add(ei);
   return saveMap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,i think this is the prefered way of doing logging stuff at server side.Anyway i wonder if its possible to add new entity to entitymanager at that point and would be wise to perform such an action in breeze interceptor.

Comment: There is no EntityManager on the server, only on the client, however you can create a separate EFContext on the server and do additional work on it if you need to, but I'd need some more info about the specific use case.

Comment: emm..i expressed myself wrong i mean its possible to add new entity to entitymanager in request interceptor at client side and would be wise to perform add operation at this point.(Client side not server side)